# RealityKit - Internal errors cause 2 seconds delay to startup

Tags: xcode, realitykit

I have a Swift RealityKit project, when I load the scene, I get a delay where Xcode spits out the following messages, which aren't related to any code I have written.

My app works fine, apart from the 2ish seconds that Xcode is complaining about these unknown things.

Can anyone shed any light on what I might have turned on that is causing this? I just need to kill whatever is delaying my startup

```
021-01-21 14:33:18.994011+0000 AppName[1396:516729] DEFAULTS: (intermediatePathOverride)=>(<null>)
2021-01-21 14:33:18.994808+0000 AppName[1396:516729] DEFAULTS: (logLevel)=>(3)
2021-01-21 14:33:18.994991+0000 AppName[1396:516729] DEFAULTS: (jasperColorStillsRunCorrection)=>(1)
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'preliminary:anchoring:type' to a prim path (/)
Warning (secondary thread): in AppendProperty at line 859 of sdf/path.cpp -- Can only append a property 'triggers' to a prim path (/)
2021-01-21 14:33:19.303829+0000 AppName[1396:516840] [Graphics] Failed to find reflection for buffer clusterIndexTable
```

and sometimes

```
2021-01-21 14:33:17.230591+0000 AppName[1396:516500] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
2021-01-21 14:33:17.391737+0000 AppName[1396:516500] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
2021-01-21 14:33:17.391784+0000 AppName[1396:516500] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
Json Parse Error line 22: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableGuidedFilterOcclusion' - skipping.
```

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar trouble, and the problem was in my model. My solution was to change my model to a valid **.usdz** file. You can find some template models in here to check if it works https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/